# Envers - Showing audit data with relationships

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-envers

- I added `@Audited` in my entities;
- I created my listener to add the user ID to `revinfo`;
- I can filter audited data with user id, entity class, min and max date, using:

  ```
  public <T extends BaseModel> List<Object[]> buscar(Class<T> clazz, Usuario usuario, java.util.Date inicio, java.util.Date fim){
  GregorianCalendar novo = new GregorianCalendar();
  novo.setTime(fim);
  novo.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

  AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(getEm());
  return reader.createQuery()
      .forRevisionsOfEntity(clazz, false, true)
      .add(AuditEntity.revisionProperty("usuario")
          .eq(usuario))
      .add(AuditEntity.revisionProperty("revtstmp")
          .between(inicio.getTime(), novo.getTime().getTime()))
      .addOrder(AuditEntity.property("id")
          .asc())
      .getResultList();

  }
  ```

But all relationships are lazy, including the `@ManyToOne`.

I found many post about problems with `@OneToMany`, but this is not the case

What can I do to access these properties?

PS: I tried, but could not highlight the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All relations in the objects returned by Envers are lazy, regardless if it's a one-to-many or many-to-one.

In an object, to access the related object's properties just call the getter :)

In a query, it's not possible. Joins are not supported, also regardless of the relation type. You can only constraint the id of the related entity, but not its properties.

Comment: So the solution is to make a new query by selecting entities by ID, right?

Comment: @adamw could you show me the code example? Because I´m having the same problem. But my object is null, but when I debug, one class method called handler has the id.

Answer (score 0):

From version 4.x in hibernate-envers you do not need to configure the listeners. you can easily audit an entity with @Audited.